# How to calculate the maximum measure level on the spectrum analyser?

Tags: bandwidth, spectrum-analyzer, detector

Suppose that all individual spectrum lines in the range from 1 MHz to 2 MHz have the same level of 40 dBuV. The distance between the spectrum lines is 35 kHz. Measurements were performed using a peak detector, a resolution bandwidth of 9 kHz, and a video bandwidth of 30 kHz. What is the maximum measured level when the resolution band is increased to 120 kHz and the video bandwidth is raised to 1 MHz?

Can I use this peak voltage formula:

Upeak = √Ptot = √4 . √P = U + 6 dB = 40 dBuV + 6 dB = 46 dBuV

Is it right?